# yii2: getting image path from string - "Class 'app\models\DOMXPath' not found"

Tags: php, image, yii, yii2

I'm trying to get image path by using the codes below. It works on PHP without frameworks. However, when I try to use it on yii2 framework, I will have an error message "`Class 'app\models\DOMXPath' not found`".

```
$image_tag = "<img src='test.com/image.jpg' border='0' title='Click Here'>";
$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($image_tag));
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
```

Is there a way to get image path using yii2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a namespacing issue. I assume you are in the `app\models` namespace but you're trying to use a class from the base namespace.

Try:

```
$xpath = new \DOMXPath(\DOMDocument::loadHTML($image_tag));
// OR:
use DOMXPath;
use DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXPath(DOMDocument::loadHTML($image_tag));
```

You should also be using a `try {} catch {}` block for catching errors opposed to using the `@` symbol, which can just make bug tracking hard in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I use this to solve my problem. "$xpath = new \DOMXPath(@\DOMDocument::loadHTML($image_tag));"